# jQuery Animate() hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery for the first time, specifically on my own website, and I'm using the animate function to make an email tab move down slightly when hovered upon (check it out in the top right: http://www.tommaxwell.me). However, I don't know how to make the animation pause after completing. I can make the first animation and the animation necessary to have it return to its original state, but I want it to return to its original state after the user moves their cursor away. Here's the code, and keep in mind I realize why it doesn't work, I just don't know a solution as I'm new to jQuery.

```
$("#emailme").hover(function(){
  $("#emailme").animate({
    paddingTop: "15px"
  }, 100, function() {
    $("#emailme").animate({
        paddingTop: "10px"
    }, 100)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the functions `$element.mouseover(fn)` and `$element.mouseout(fn)`.

So it should be like this:

```
$("#emailme").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        paddingTop: "15px"
    }, 100);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        paddingTop: "10px"
    }, 100);
});
```

This means that attach event handlers to two different events: when you move your mouse over the element it expands and when you move your mouse out it subtracts - just as you want it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll choose your answer as the right one as soon as SO lets me. :)

Comment: The answer above is also correct but I prefer to separate things by moving different actions to different event bindings as this helps with code maintenance later on.

Comment: @VytautasButkus The hover signature does exactly the same thing anyway. It binds a mouseenter and mouseleave handler and saves you a few keystrokes. They are separate event bindings.

Comment: @Asad - yes I know that but as I already said "saving a few keystrokes" is not a case when it comes to code readability later on.

Comment: @VytautasButkus How does including the word `mouseout` improve readability?

Comment: @Asad suppose you haven't read .hover() documentation and you don't know what second handler does.

At the end you could write code like this:
    var expand = function(){
        $(this).animate({
            paddingTop: "15px"
        }, 100);
    }, subtract = function(){
        $(this).animate({
            paddingTop: "10px"
        }, 100);
    }
    $("#emailme").mouseover(expand).mouseout(subtract);

Comment: @VytautasButkus That's just silly, I told the asker what it does. *Suppose you haven't read any examples with method chaining and don't know how it works?* By the way, you're binding to the wrong events. Hover is equivalent to mouseenter and mouseleave, not mouseover and mouseout. As your code stands, any child elements will trigger the mouseout/mouseover handlers.

Comment: @Asad so suppose I just taught asker how to code correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `hover` is the callback to invoke when the user moves their mouse away.

```
$("#emailme").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        paddingTop: "15px"
    }, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        paddingTop: "10px"
    }, 100)
});
```

So the general idea is:

```
$('selector').hover(function(){
    //stuff to do on mouse in
}, function(){
    //stuff to do on mouse out
});
```